# Filter an array on array of arrays of objects by matching a property of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-map

I have a case where I have Array of Arrays and each inner array has multiple objects as below:

```
const arrayOfArraysOfObjects = [
  [
    { name: 'abv', id: '1212' },
    { name: 'gfgf', id: '887' },
    { name: 'John', id: '886' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'abv', id: '1242' },
    { name: 'gfgf', id: '837' },
    { name: 'John', id: '816' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'abv', id: '1242' },
    { name: 'gfgf', id: '837' },
    { name: 'John', id: '896' }
  ]
];
```

I want to pull out the array which contains the object whose property `id` is matching with any particular number, say 896

With ES6 I tried this

```
rawList = arrayOfArraysOfObjects.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => acc || obj[curr] === my.id, false));
return rawList;
```

here my.id is 896

but this didn't work, **MY EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
[
   { name: 'abv', id: '1012' },
   { name: 'gfgf', id: '881' },
   { name: 'John', id: '896' }
]
```

hence, tried correcting it as:

```
rawList = arrayOfArraysOfObjects.map((apprGrp) => {
  const filteredList = apprGrp.filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => acc || obj[curr] === my.id, false));
  return filteredList;
});
```

this also didnt gave me the above metioned desired result.
Please suggest how can I correct this to get the desired results

Comment: Whats your expected output ?

Comment: Highlighted the expected with text MY EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Comment: Can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a array filter and a find to filter by the item

```js
const arrayOfArraysOfObjects = [
  [
   { name: 'abv', id: '1212' },
   { name: 'gfgf', id: '887' },
   { name: 'John', id: '886' }
  ],
  [
   { name: 'abv', id: '1242' },
   { name: 'gfgf', id: '837' },
   { name: 'John', id: '816' }
  ],
  [
   { name: 'abv', id: '1242' },
   { name: 'gfgf', id: '837' },
   { name: 'John', id: '896' }
  ]
];

console.log(arrayOfArraysOfObjects.filter(x => x.find(y => y.id === '896')).flat());
```

Comment: this would still give me Array of Array of Object, I am expecting an array of object only

Comment: Perfect!! Answer Perfect solution.. Thanks Guru

Answer (score 1):

You can check this solution.

```js
const data = [
  [
    { name: "abv", id: "1212" },
    { name: "gfgf", id: "887" },
    { name: "John", id: "886" },
  ],
  [
    { name: "abv", id: "1242" },
    { name: "gfgf", id: "837" },
    { name: "John", id: "816" },
  ],
  [
    { name: "abv", id: "1242" },
    { name: "gfgf", id: "837" },
    { name: "John", id: "896" },
  ],
];

const filterData = (id) => data.filter((arr) => arr.some((obj) => obj.id == id));

console.log(filterData(837));
```

Comment: ideally this would have been my answer if I needed more than one Array which contains this ID, My case would have this ID in only one array

Comment: @Noob oh i see, then just using a `flat` will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking to find a single sub-array with the required `id` use `Array.find()` instead of `Array.filter()`. Use `Array.some()` to check if the current sub-array contains the `id`:

```js
const data = [[{"name":"abv","id":"1212"},{"name":"gfgf","id":"887"},{"name":"John","id":"886"}],[{"name":"abv","id":"1242"},{"name":"gfgf","id":"837"},{"name":"John","id":"816"}],[{"name":"abv","id":"1242"},{"name":"gfgf","id":"837"},{"name":"John","id":"896"}]];

const findSubArray = id => data.find(arr => arr.some(o => o.id === id));

console.log(findSubArray('837'));
```